# Counting multiple columns in one query

Tags: mysql

Say I have the following tables,

lesson

```
id    description
-----------------
1     science
2     english
3     maths
```

lesson_student_rel

```
lesson_id   student_id
----------------------
1           1
1           2
1           3
2           1
3           1
3           3
```

lesson_tutor_rel

```
lesson_id   tutor_id
--------------------
1           1
2           1
2           2
```

lesson_assistant_rel

```
lesson_id   assistant_id
------------------------
1           1
1           2
3           2
```

I would like to count the total number of students, tutors and assistants for each lesson so I get a result like,

```
lesson_id   student_count   tutor_count   assistant_count
---------------------------------------------------------
1           3               1             2
2           1               2             0
3           2               0             1
```

I think I've been looking at this too long now and have got completely stuck, I've found a few similar questions but nothing that seems to answer this. Is it possible to do with one query? Any pointers would be good - an answer would be amazing.

Thanks!

Comment: Inner join all tables on lesson.id. Next put lesson.id in select together with count on all the other ids and group by id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does it for you:

```
SELECT l.id,COUNT(DISTINCT lsr.student_id) student_count,COUNT(DISTINCT ltr.tutor_id) tutor_count
,COUNT(DISTINCT lar.assistant_id) assistant_count
FROM lesson l
LEFT JOIN lesson_student_rel lsr ON lsr.lesson_id=l.id
LEFT JOIN lesson_tutor_rel ltr ON ltr.lesson_id=l.id
LEFT JOIN lesson_assistant_rel lar ON lar.lesson_id=l.id
GROUP BY l.id
```